# Hive DATE manipulation in a query

Tags: sql, hive

I am trying to run a Hive QUERy
I have a table with lets say 3 columns.
Of one is a date column with data as :

a       d         2014-04-01
   b       e         2014-04-03
   c       f         2014-04-20

Now I want to pick the Maximum date from the above data and do a difference with the current date ( current date lets assume is 2014-04-24) and add the difference to the output.
What I mean is ; the query should pick 2014-04-20 and subtract it with current date to give an output as 4 and then add this difference to all the dates to have an output as :

a            d         2014-04-05
   b            e         2014-04-07
   c            f         2014-04-24

I tried this but it runs into a semantic issue:

> select A, B,  date_add( SOMEDATE, datediff(to_date(
>   FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP() )), max(SOMEDATE))) As SOMEDATE

Comment: you need two select statements or a sub-query or a cte.  Which depends on the platform you are using, which you don't explain.

Comment: I am running this on Hive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doable using Hive date udf's  (DATEDIFF, FROM_UNIXTIME, UNIX_TIMESTAMP, DATE_ADD): 
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-DateFunctions

Assuming your source table definition is: *DateSource(col1 string, col2 string, myDate string)*

The query would be:

```
SELECT col1, col2, myDate, DATE_ADD(myDate,daysDiff) as adjustedDate 
FROM DateSource
JOIN
  (
    SELECT DATEDIFF(FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(),"yyyy-MM-dd"),maxDate) as daysDiff 
      FROM 
       (
         SELECT max(myDate) as maxDate FROM DateSource
       ) maxDate
  ) diffDate;
```