# How to do string date manipulation in HIVE?

Tags: date, hadoop, hive

I have a string field in the format of 'yyyymmdd' representing a date. The query needs to get the previous third day's data. Could you please let me know how to manipulate it? I tried a couple of ways, but failed.

Here is the sudo code/logic -

```
select uu_id
from tbl_1
where day=day -3 (days)

where day = date_add(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(day,'yyyyMMdd'),'yyyy-MM-dd'),-3)
```

Any pointers would be helpful!

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to use the following Hive UDF.

```
date_sub(string startdate, int days)
Subtracts a number of days to startdate: date_sub('2008-12-31', 1) = '2008-12-30'.
```

Please refer the below link for detailed explanations of Date UDF.

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-DateFunctions.

This SO post gives a nice idea

[Hive DATE manipulation in a query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23272577/hive-date-manipulation-in-a-query)